# Отвалился перевод пояснения закрытого вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Вопрос недавно был закрыт: [Настройка postback](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634999/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-postback)

Сейчас вижу в плашке о закрытии:

> объявлен 3 часа назад требующим правки участниками rjhdby, Vadizar,
>   cheops, Denis Bubnov, Yuri, так как вопрос слишком общий
>
> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough
>   detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct
>   questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this
>   question.
>
> Если вопрос можно переформулировать согласно правилам,
>   изложенным в справке, отредактируйте его.

Перевод потерялся.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перевод не то чтобы потерялся, а просто изменилась исходная формулировка.

Перевёл новую строку так:

> Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. «Как задать хороший вопрос?» для прояснения ситуации.

В transifex для этого текста заведены две строки: [Tx10183](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/109269618?key=ffdfafc669d06c67b9cfcab9c885d767), [Tx10184](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/109269619?key=42c12ef238139e87b09e5c9aef84789f).

Скорее всего, перевод появится в ближайший понедельник, т.к. на выходных сайт обычно не пересобирается.

Comment: А нельзя ли вот эти ваши ссылки на транзифекс как-нибудь в тексте ответа обозначить, для непосвящённых?

Comment: @vp_arth для непосвященных они не нужны :) По сути эти ссылки нужны только чтобы в случае чего быстро подправить строки, а не искать их в базе по-новой.

Comment: Ну я так не играю... (с) Карлсон

Comment: @vp_arth [подключайтесь к команде локализации!](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/176217)

Comment: Подключишься к вам, ага) https://habrastorage.org/files/2ac/de0/07c/2acde007cca4459b90292b981c9e2802.png

Comment: @vp_arth обещанного три года ждут :-D

Comment: @vp_arth Готово!